# R Lattice Graphics - Removing axes from particular panels

Tags: r, graphics, lattice

I am using the following code to generate the enclosed figure:

```
xyplot(data$SA..m2.g.~ date2 | data$RH*data$type, groups=data$env,
  pch=c(19,15,1), col=c("gray50","black","black"),cex=1.3,
  xlab=list("Time (days)", cex=1.6), ylab=list(ylabel,cex=1.6),
  scales=list(alternating = 1, cex=1.1, y=list(relation="free",
  limits = rep(list(c(0, 20), c(0, 20), c(0, 20), c(0, 300), c(0,300), c(0,300))))))
```

I have used the `relation="free"` parameter so that the "surface areas" on the top and bottom rows can be independently set to the fixed values `c(0,300)` and `c(0,20)`, respectively.  However, I want to remove the space between the panels and only use one set of axes on the left. When I use the `draw=FALSE` parameter, all the axes disappear.  How do I remove the axes/labels from the middle and right panels?  Even better would be to connect the three panels together and only use the left-most set of axes.  Sorry, don't have enough reputation points to actually post the images.

Comment: You can put a link to your picture and someone with more reputation can edit your question to add it.

Comment: I doubt that someone will handle this without sample data. And when revise it: note that xyplot(data$SA...) is a quite uncommon notation. The usual way is to supply  data=data as argument, and then omit all data$ in the formula and groups.